# Why does my circle on my sphere becoming a figure eight?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, angle

here is the code in question to the title of this issue I have. I have hand-derived the formulas behind my code so it doesnt seem to be wrong...

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import random as rdm

resol = 30
resolcirc = 15
r=1

########## THE SPHERE ##########
phi = np.linspace(0, np.pi*((resol-1)/resol), resol)
theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi*((resol*2-1)/resol*2), resol*2)
phi, theta = np.meshgrid(phi, theta)

x = r * np.sin(phi) * np.cos(theta)
y = r * np.sin(phi) * np.sin(theta)
z = r * np.cos(phi)    

########## THE RANDOM POINT ##########
r1=1

randphi = rdm.random()*np.pi 
randtheta = rdm.random()*2*np.pi

x1 = r1 * np.sin(randphi) * np.cos(randtheta)
y2 = r1 * np.sin(randphi) * np.sin(randtheta)
z3 = r1 * np.cos(randphi) 

radpoint = 0.5

########## THE RANDOM CIRCLE ##########
rcirc=0.2
gamma = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi*((resol-1)/resol), resol)

rotanglephi = -1 * rcirc * np.cos(gamma) 
rotangletheta = rcirc * np.sin(gamma)

psitheta=2*np.sin(-1*rcirc*np.cos(gamma)/r)
psiphi=2*np.sin(rcirc*np.sin(gamma)/r)

x1 = r1 * np.sin(randphi+psiphi) * np.cos(randtheta+psitheta)
y2 = r1 * np.sin(randphi+psiphi) * np.sin(randtheta+psitheta)
z3 = r1 * np.cos(randphi+psiphi) 

########## THE PLOT ###########
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(x, y, z, c='y', marker='.')
ax.scatter(x1,y2,z3, c='r', marker = 'x',s=50)

plt.tight_layout()
#plt.axis('off')

plt.show()
```

Normally it works totally fine as intended, as such:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuJ02.png)

However, I cannot for the life of me troubleshoot why it is giving me this funky behavior at the top and bottom of the sphere:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4qWi.png)

This the the absolute first step of this code, where I will need to create a point, and make a ring around it which will move in an orbit on this spherical surface. Help is massively appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Your solution does not define a circle it seems depending upon your theta/phi

look at the graph with values, for

`randphi = np.pi / 8
randtheta = -np.pi / 4`

I would suggest defining your circle as an intersection of a plane with a sphere [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/943383/determine-circle-of-intersection-of-plane-and-sphere)

Comment: The point is I have to make this circle from the generation via the R-vector on the sphere, as I will be moving the R-vector along the sphere and intend to have collision physics. Perhaps a better idea is coordinate rotations?

Comment: i guess if you are moving a circle over the sphere you have to make sure the circle is on a plane defined by the "r" vector (this will be the normal to the plane).  with a point on the plane / sphere that is the "radius" of the circle.  so depending upon the planes distance from the sphere (r2, in your work) you will have an intersection or not?

Comment: if you simply want to detect a collision then it's quite simple, r1 <= r; but if you are interested in the case when r1 < r and you have the plane defined then http://www.ambrsoft.com/TrigoCalc/Sphere/SpherePlaneIntersection_.htm